How to make a palette button to define subscripts as symbols
I want to have a palette that includes a button for defining subscripted variables as symbols. As this is only needed once per session, I also want the button to change colour when pressed. The code I am trying is below. However, whilst it changes colour when pressed it does not change subscripted variables to symbols. Yet if I use the Symbolize function on its own i.e. not in a button, it works. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
  Dynamic@Button["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(y\)]\)",
    c = RGBColor[1, .1, .1];
      Needs["Notation`"];
      ?Notation`Symbolize[NotationTemplateTag[Subscript[_, _]] ];
    RunScheduledTask[
     RemoveScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask], {0}, AbsoluteTime[] + 3], 
    Appearance -> {"DialogBox", "Palette"}, FrameMargins -> 0, 
    Background -> c, ImageSize -> 92, Method -> "Queued"], 
  Initialization :> {c = White}]```


It's not clear what "defining subscripted variables as symbols" means.  Can you show an example that works without the button, something we can reproduce and use as a goal? After clearing two typos in your code (the at-sign and the question mark), I got an error message that said Symbolize cannot be used outside the Notation Palette, which has been my experience.  I am not sure it is possible to do what you want without using the Notation Palette. But, tell us first how you do it with the Notation Palette.

To clarify what I mean Head[Subscript[A, s]] normally returns Subscript. I need it to return Symbol The above expression should work for any subscripted variable. With further work, I have found that using the Symbolize statement on its own, with nothing else, in the button works, provided, you have already called the Notation palette, but I would like to call the notation palette and run the Symbolize expression in one button press. I would also like to be able to change the colour of the button when pressed but adding anything to the button means the Symbolize function does not work.
